# Javascript variables resetting

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a webapp locally and I have a 'settings' page. The user can change the variables and the Javascript is supposed to save the values but it seems to reset them back to 1 straight after it changes them.

HTML:

```
<body onload="getSettings()">
        <h1>Instance Load Manager - Settings</h1>
        <div id="uploader">
            <h2>Terraform file upload:</h2>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple onchange="moveFile()" />
        </div>
        <a href="index.html">
            <div id="settingsButton">
                <h3>Back</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div id ="settingsForm">
            <form>
                Maximum instances:<br>
                <input type="text" id="maxInst" name="max instances"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" onclick="updateSettings()">
        </div>
    </body>
```

Javascript:

```
var maxInstances = 1;

function updateSettings()
{
    maxInstances = document.getElementById("maxInst").value;
    alert(maxInstances);
}

function getSettings()
{
    document.getElementById("maxInst").value = maxInstances;
}
```

Help appreciated :)

Comment: save in a json file your settings with the user ip or something like an unique id

Comment: Your `html` is invalid...where is your closing `form` tag?

Comment: When you press enter (or click submit) in the text fields, it causes form submit, which reloads the page, which reloads your javascript. Puff, your variables are gone. If you have a form, use it correctly (specify form action, write server handler).  If you want to do it purely in JS, then don't use a form. Instead, handle onchange events in text fields and persist to local storage or something. In any case, you got __a lot__ of reading to do.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I didn't even see I hadn't closed the form, so thanks - silly mistake. Sergio, you are saying that I should have the function call for the form action? Just to clarify for everyone - this webapp will never be hosted online and is just going to be the UI component of a student project I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent your page from refreshing after submitting the form.

```
function updateSettings(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    maxInstances = document.getElementById("maxInst").value;
    alert(maxInstances);
}
```

Comment: Why not just ditch the form?